# Vim words in Comment

Tags: vim, comments

I'm using the built-in function *search()* in Vim script to find certain words like "class".

I want to know whether the word is in Comment or not.

I'm using C++ language.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Might be relevant: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2h7gjk/how_to_detect_if_cursors_current_position_is/

Comment: Specifiy the language !

Comment: Thanks. The answer on that website helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either move the cursor to `search()` result, or use `searchpos()`. Then, use the current/result coordinates `synID + synIDattr` against `comment`.

For instance, if you don't use  `n` flag in `search()`,

```
:let is_in_a_comment = synIDattr(synID(line('.'),col('.')-1,1),'name') =~? 'comment'
```

Hence my [`lh#syntax#is_a_comment_at(lin,col)` and `lh#syntax#is_a_comment(mark)` functions.](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/syntax.vim#L156)

NB, In C++ you may need to match doxygen as well.

PS: On the subject lately I came up with an experiment: `lh#syntax#getline_without()`, it returns `getline()` result but stripped of the syntax elements we are not interested in. It can be useful to analyse a file, but not to jump to various positions within it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is an efficient way.